# Why I am getting different result in different JVM for following code

Tags: java, jvm

```
String s="hel"+"lo"

if(s == "hello")
 {
    //print true 

}
else
{
 //print false 
}
```

Sun jvm = true
Ibm jvm = false

Why this discrepancy ?

Comment: Did you compile with the javac from the distribution tested?  What versions were they?  The thing you are seeing is "string interning".

Comment: I know that using "".equals() should be the right way .I am just curious why we are getting above behavior in different JVM .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` is for reference comparison.

For the Sun JVM this behaviour is most likely due to String pool.
For IBM JVM it could be a different implemenation.

If you need object comparison use `equals`

Answer (score 2):

The `==` only succeedes if the string is interned after construction.  I believe the crucial point is if javac optimizes the `+` at compile time or not, i.e. if the JVM sees

```
String s = "hello"
```

or

```
String s = "hell" + "lo".
```

(by the way, this must be a copy paste error - there will be three l's in the concatenated value)

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used to check if both object are referring to same object.
Use `if(object1.equals(object))` to check if contents of both object are equal

Answer (score 1):

I would point out that Java 7 and 6 behave differently with the interned Strings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065337/intern-behaving-differently-in-java-6-and-java-7)

If you are using sun Java 7, maybe the IBM jvm is still working as Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

While not answering your question: doing == on strings is most likely not what you wanted in the first place.

```
    if(s.equals("hello")) {
```

might be what you really wanted to do ...

Edit: since "==" compares references, depending on their implementation of how new strings are created both jvms could be right with their results at the same time! "==" is NOT a valid operator to check the equality of strings in Java.