# Difference between using Java 6 and java 7 in android

Tags: java, android

I want to know the difference between java 6 and java 7 while creating android app.

As i have seen a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065337/intern-behaving-differently-in-java-6-and-java-7). and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119638/differences-in-auto-unboxing-between-java-6-vs-java-7). Which should we use and what are the other issue which can occur while using them.

Answer (score 0):

In general Java 7 is on Android not supported. So you have to use Java 6 on Android.

Java 7 is supported from Android API 19 (KitKat 4.4), but it will fail on any other version below.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android

Comment: No, it won't fail, you're making that up. You can even use Java 8, thought technically it's not supported, so I wouldn't recommend it.