# Java check equality for Strings

Tags: java, string, equality

**Edited:** I have tested this code in java and the printed output was **"true"**, while the compiler compares the reference and not the value of Strings why this is "true"?

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String s1 = "string";
        String s2 = "string";
        System.out.println(""+(s1==s2));
    }
}
```

Comment: java 7 also it will print `true`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Might playing with constant pool :)

Comment: Was your Java 6 JRE from Sun/Oracle or an alternative JRE?

Comment: Ok, Thank you guys. I was wrong. I replaced the statement "System.out.println(""+(s1==s2));" 
with this two statements and the result was **"false"**. Thanks.

String s3 = "stringstring";
System.out.println(""+(s3==s1+s2));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String equality rules have not changed in Java 8 and `s1==s2` prints always `true` in this case since they both point to the same memory location in constant pool, which typically located on heap memory.

I just checked with Java6 and it's true.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I was wrong. I replaced the statement "System.out.println(""+(s1==s2));" with this two statements and the result was "false". Thanks. String s3 = "stringstring"; System.out.println(""+(s3==s1+s2));

Comment: @Mansur Answer after edit of question : because both point to the same memory location in constant pool.

Answer (score 1):

There has been no change, the == operator checks if two references point to the same object. String literals are placed in the string pool. So "string" is placed in the string pool, s1 and s2 both point to that, hence an output of true.

Answer (score 1):

In your edited question, you have defined two *String literals*. As per [JLS § 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) these literals are *interned*:

> a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Therefore reference equality using `==` will always return `true` for `s1 == s2` where:

```
String s1 = "string";
String s2 = "string";
```

The JLS states (almost exactly) the same for [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) and [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/lexical.html#3.10.5)

Note though that there are some subtle differences in the way string interning works between certain JDK versions. See, for instance ["intern() behaving differently in Java 6 and Java 7"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7090813/1945631)

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the compiler to decide, in this case, whether `s1 == s2`. The condition is testing whether `s1` and `s2` are the same object. This is likely to be true, as a sensible compiler would have a constant pool, but not necessarily so.

However, your intent is comparing the strings, not the objects, so `equals()` is the correct method and the use of == is incorrect for that.

Comment: No compilers would maintain a constant pool. JVM does.